# BlueZ BLE GATT write request (0x12) instead of (0x16)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatt

I am trying to reverse engineer a BLE device for research. The BLE device does not require pairing.

One of the commands that are written that I can see in wireshark is write to a specific handle. When I try to do the same using the Gatttool write request:

> sudo gatttool -i hci0 -b 54:6C:0E:21:F5:99 --char-write-req -a 0x0030
>   -n 110100701301000110010030721000d68c054688df413aa89fb3cfab3d6457172000053958839fa147ac53c129eafc524829bc9ed7655fe96c9f641745c4e07cf044

It uses a 0x16 prepare write request instead and there seems to be some error as well. Below is an image of both captures, the left side is the GAtttool request and the right side is the request done by the phone.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The communication to the right has earlier negotiated a larger MTU. That's why it can send the whole value in one request.